# Visualise data from kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, data-visualization, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to kafka. I have written a simple producer script which writes JSON data in the form of latlong coordinates and another consumer app that can read the latlong data as it is being produced. If I wish to plot the latlong data using D3js or highcharts how do I it? Any suggestions or links would be greatly appreciated. I did my research but I couldn't find any relevant tutorials yet.

Answer (score 2):

D3.js is a front-end technology. Kafka is backend.

You need some mechanism to forward data from a Kafka consumer to a given browser. Websockets is one option, and there's several resources out there about it

For example, https://github.com/sulthan309/Live-Dashboard-using-Kafka-and-Spring-Websocket

The alternative is to feed the data into a system like Druid, InfluxDB, Elasticsearch, or other storage system intended for time-series numerical data, from which you can use real BI tools to analyze it